# How to define the response body object, in a NestJs-generated Swagger document?

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs

I'm Using NestJs and its Swagger plugin to auto-generate documentation of my API.

Problem is, I cant figure out how to make the **response** schema appear in the documentation. In my GET routes, all i get is "Code 200", with no data structure.

I have a typical setup, where a controller method uses a corresponding service method, which in turn uses a TypeOrm repository. For example:

```
@Get()
 findAll() {    
   return this.usersService.findAll();
}
```

I tried using the *@ApiResponse* decorator, but didn't really see any way to make it serve this purpose. Also, creating a user.dto.ts and making it the return type of the controller route didn't do any good.

Eventually, this is what i get in the Swagger:

[image: swagger]

How can i define the response body schema?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `type` and `isArray` properties in conjunction with the `ApiResponse` family of decorators. For example:

```
@ApiOkResponse({
    description: 'The user records',
    type: User,
    isArray: true
})
@Get()
 findAll() {    
   return this.usersService.findAll();
}
```

Additionally, consider using the [Swagger CLI plugin](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/cli-plugin) to help you have these decorators applied automatically during build time instead of you having to keep everything in sync manually.

Comment: This worked once the "type" property referred to a simple dto, not to the User entity of Typeorm. Which one did you mean, by type:User? Anyhow, thanx!

Comment: It needs to be a DTO, unless you're using the Swagger CLI plugin which can infer a lot of this stuff for you automatically

Comment: Yes so I used the plugin, but it didn't seem to infer the data correctly from the User entity that is eventually returned by the route. Perhaps some tweaking is needed?

Answer (score 8):

You can annotate controller action with `ApiExtraModels`:

```
import { ApiExtraModels, ApiResponse, getSchemaPath } from '@nestjs/swagger'
import { Controller, Get, Param } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {


 @ApiExtraModels(UserDto)
 @ApiResponse({
    status: 200,
    schema: {
      $ref: getSchemaPath(UserDto),
    },
  })
  @Get('/:userId')
  getById(@Param('userId') userId: string): UserDto {
     ... something happens ... 
     return myUserDto;
  }

}
```

and you have to also annotate `UserDto` properties with `ApiProperty`:

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger'
import { Expose } from 'class-transformer'
import { IsString } from 'class-validator'

export class UserDto {

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  @Expose()
  id: string;
}
```

Btw, check [CLI plugin for generating ApiProperty](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/cli-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

> Also, creating a user.dto.ts and making it the return type of the controller route didn't do any good.

I faced a similar issue, yet adding type annotation to the controller route / service method did it for me (also using the Swagger CLI plugin).

```
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';

@Get()
findAll(): Promise<User[]> {    
  return this.usersService.findAll();
}
```

This changed the Swagger specs for the endpoint response

```
{
  // ...
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
-                    "type": "object"
+                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/User"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
  // ...
}
```

and added the `User` schema.