# ZOD to swagger API Dto class for nestjs swagger

Tags: swagger, nestjs, dto

How can I turn this zod schema into the CountryDto for the swagger user?  I am using nestjs with zod for input validation. Using nesjs/swagger package for swagger.

```
export const CountrySchema = z
  .object({
    name: z.string({
      required_error: 'Name is required',
      invalid_type_error: 'Name is invalid',
    }),
    iso2: z.string({
      required_error: 'iso2 is required',
      invalid_type_error: 'iso2 is invalid',
    }),
    iso3: z.string({
      required_error: 'iso3 is required',
      invalid_type_error: 'iso3 is invalid',
    }),
    dialCode: z.string({
      required_error: 'dialCode is required',
      invalid_type_error: 'dialCode is invalid',
    }),
    flagUrl: z.string({
      required_error: 'flagUrl is required',
      invalid_type_error: 'flagUrl is invalid',
    }),
  })
  .required();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define the response body object, in a NestJs-generated Swagger document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70897363/how-to-define-the-response-body-object-in-a-nestjs-generated-swagger-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the lib: https://github.com/colinhacks/zod

And do:

```
import { createZodDto } from 'nestjs-zod';
import { z } from 'nestjs-zod/z';

// Define Zod schema for CountrySchema
const CountrySchema = z.object({
  // ... (your schema definition here)
});

// Create DTO class using createZodDto
export class CountryDTO extends createZodDto(CountrySchema) {}
```

You need to make some configurations in your main.ts/js

You need to import PatchNestJsSwagger into the main.ts and call it, like this:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SwaggerModule, DocumentBuilder } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { patchNestJsSwagger } from 'nestjs-zod';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Env } from './env';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const configService = app.get<ConfigService<Env, true>>(ConfigService);
  patchNestJsSwagger();

  app.enableCors();

  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Area API')
    .setDescription('Uma api para uma área de membros')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addTag('MEMBROS')
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api-docs', app, document);

  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
  const port = configService.get('PORT', { infer: true });
  await app.listen(port);
  Logger.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${port}`, 'Bootstrap');
}
  bootstrap();
```

You can find more informations in the nestjs/zod lib quoted in the start of the response.